# Decompositions of exterior products

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products, exterior-algebra, almost-complex

Let $V$ be a real vector space equipped with an almost complex structure $J$ and denote the complexification by $V_\mathbb C$. The complexified vector space splits into the eigenspaces $V^{1,0}$ and $V^{0,1}$. We have the following now considering the exterior powers: $$\bigwedge^*V_\mathbb C = \bigoplus_{k=0}^d \bigwedge^k V_\mathbb{C}$$ where $d$ is the dimension of $V_\mathbb{C}$ and $$\bigwedge^kV_\mathbb C = \bigwedge^k V^{1,0} \oplus V^{0,1} \cong \bigoplus_{p+q=k} \bigwedge^p V^{1,0} \otimes \bigwedge^q V^{0,1}$$ where if I understood correctly the isomorphism $$\bigwedge^k V^{1,0} \oplus V^{0,1} \cong \bigoplus_{p+q=k} \bigwedge^p V^{1,0} \otimes \bigwedge^q V^{0,1}$$ is given by $$(v_1\wedge \dots \wedge v_p) \otimes (w_1\wedge \dots \wedge w_q) \mapsto v_1\wedge \dots \wedge v_p \wedge w_1\wedge \dots \wedge w_q$$ and the inverse would then just be $$v_1\wedge \dots \wedge v_p \wedge w_1\wedge \dots \wedge w_q \mapsto (v_1\wedge \dots \wedge v_p) \otimes (w_1\wedge \dots \wedge w_q).$$

I have two questions regarding this.

1. The element $(v_1\wedge \dots \wedge v_p) \otimes (w_1\wedge \dots \wedge w_q) \in \bigoplus_{p+q=k} \bigwedge^p V^{1,0} \otimes \bigwedge^q V^{0,1}$ is a pure tensor right? Arbitary elements of this space would be finite linear combinations of such elements? I'm guessing that $v \in \bigwedge^*V_\mathbb C$ takes the form $$v=\sum v_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge v_{i_m}$$ where $v_{i_j} \in \bigwedge^{i_j} V_\mathbb{C}$ so even all of the summands would decompose to further summations?
2. There are supposedly projections $\pi^k :\bigwedge^*V_\mathbb C \to \bigwedge^k V_\mathbb C$ and $\pi^{p,q}:\bigwedge^*V_\mathbb C \to \bigwedge^{p,q} V:= \bigwedge^{p} V^{1,0} \otimes \bigwedge^{q}V^{0,1}$ and these should be in some sense natural. What are these projections explicitly? I don't quite understand them.

Maybe some simple examples would help to illustrate this? Appreciations in advance for anyone who can help me out here.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. They just take the appropriate graded component, i.e. they delete everything except what's in degree $k$ or bidegree $(p, q)$ respectively.

Comment: I think I got something but I don't know if this is correct. For the first one i.e. $\pi^k : \bigwedge^\ast V_\mathbb C \to \bigwedge^k V_\mathbb C$ the map would be $$\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_k \mapsto \alpha_k$$ and for $\pi^{p,q}:\bigwedge^\ast V_\mathbb C \to \bigwedge^{p,q} V$  the map would be $$\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{p+q=k} \alpha^{p,q} \mapsto \alpha^{p,q}.$$ This however requires $\alpha_k$ to break down into $\sum_{p+q=k} \alpha^{p,q}$ which I'm still a bit unsure of. @QiaochuYuan

Comment: Use the isomorphism you've already established $\bigwedge^kV_\mathbb C \cong \bigoplus_{p+q=k} \bigwedge^{p,q}V$ together with the canonical projection from the direct sum.

Comment: In which part? @NicholasTodoroff

Comment: (1) is a yes or no question, and the answer is yes. (2), referring to $\pi^{p,q}$, I thought you understood the isomorphism I wrote, in which case all you have to do is apply the canonical projection of the direct sum. Or are you saying that you don't understand this isomorphism, and that's what you need help with?

Comment: Yes the first part is clear for me. The second part is the one I'm having difficulties. I think that the maps I wrote work, but the second one seems to use the isomorphism in some way which I don't understand so yes I think that's where I need help. @NicholasTodoroff

Comment: I'm still not sure you're understanding what I'm saying, so let me ask more directly. Yes or no: Do you understand the isomorphism ${\bigwedge}^k V_{\mathbb C} \cong \oplus_{p+q=k}{\bigwedge}^{p,q}V$?

Comment: I don't think I do. @NicholasTodoroff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand\Ext{\mathop{\textstyle\bigwedge}}
\newcommand\MVects[1]{\mathop{\textstyle\bigwedge^{\mkern-2mu#1}}}
\newcommand\C{\mathbb C}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
$To answer question 2:

We need to be really careful. If we let $\Re$ be the operator which takes an $d$-dimensional complex vector space $W$ (with conjugation) to a $2d$-dimensional real vector space $\Re W$ then the following is false:
$$
  \Re\MVects kV_\C \color{red} \cong \bigoplus_{p+q=k}\MVects{p,q}V 
$$
but the following is true
$$
  \MVects k\Re V_\C \cong \bigoplus_{p+q=k}\MVects{p,q}V.
$$
To see that the first line is false, just take $k = 0$: the LHS is $\Re\C$ which has real dimension 2 but the RHS is just $\R$. The second line is actually a consequence of an algebra isomorphism
$$
  \Ext(U\oplus V) \cong \Ext U\mathbin{\hat\otimes}\Ext V
$$
where $U, V$ are vector space over the same field and $\hat\otimes$ is the $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-graded tensor product. I will not worry about proving this however, and instead focus on the exterior powers.

---

You seem to understand that we can get a map $\varphi^{p,q} : \MVects{p,q}V \to \MVects{p+q}\Re V_\C$ by just using the exterior product:
$$
  \varphi^{p,q}(v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_p\otimes w_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge w_q) = v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_P\wedge w_1\dotsb\wedge w_q.
$$
(An aside: because we're talking about $\Re V_\C$, the expression $v\wedge(iv) \ne 0$! This is because we are only using an $\R$-linear $\wedge$ over $\Re V_\C = V^{1,0} \oplus V^{0,1}$.)
We can package these maps together into a map $\varphi : \bigoplus_{p+q=k}\MVects{p,q}V \to \MVects kV_\C$ where
$$
  \varphi(\sum_{p+q=k}X_{p,q}) = \sum_{p+q=k}\varphi^{p,q}(X_{p,q})
$$
for any $X_{p,q} \in \MVects{p,q}V$. So what we want to do now is show that this is an isomorphism. This requires showing both injevtivity and surjectivity, or one just one of these as long as we make sure the dimensions match. Let's show surjectivity and then count dimensions.

- The map is surjective: Every element of $\MVects k\Re V_\C$ is of the form $\sum_iX_i\wedge Y_i$ where $X_i$ is a product of $p$ $V^{1,0}$-vectors and $Y_i$ a product of $q$ $V^{0,1}$ vectors with $p+q = k$; this follows from linearity and antisymmetry of $\wedge$ since for example
  $$\begin{aligned}
    (v_1 + iw_1)\wedge(v_2 + iw_2)
      &= v_1\wedge v_2 + v_1\wedge(iw_2) + (iw_1)\wedge v_2 + (iw_1)\wedge(iw_2)
  \\
      &= v_1\wedge v_2 + v_1\wedge(iw_2) - v_2\wedge(iw_1) + (iw_1)\wedge(iw_2).
  \end{aligned}$$
  In this case $X_1 = v_1\wedge v_2$, $Y_1 = 1$, $X_2 = v_1$, $Y_2 = iw_2$, $X_3 = -v_2$, $Y_3 = iw_1$, $X_4 = 1$, $Y_4 = (iw_1)\wedge(iw_2)$. With that established, it is trivial that
  $$
    \varphi(\sum_iX_i\otimes Y_i) = \sum_iX_i\wedge Y_i
  $$
  so $\varphi$ is surjective.
- The (real) dimensions of $\bigoplus_{p+q=k}\MVects{p,q}V$ and $\MVects kV_\C$ are respectively
  $$
    \sum_{p+q=k}{n\choose p}{n\choose q},\quad {2n\choose k}.
  $$
  Now compute
  $$
    \sum_{p+q=k}{n\choose p}{n\choose q}
      = \sum_{p=0}^k{n\choose p}{2n-n\choose k-p}
      = {2n\choose k}
  $$
  where we've used the [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

---

Now that we have a map $\varphi^{-1} : \MVects k\Re V_\C \to \bigoplus_{p+q=k}\MVects{p,q}V$, because the direct sum comes with a projection $\psi^{a,b} : \bigoplus_{p+q=k}\MVects{p,q}V \to \MVects{a,b}V$ where $a+b=k$, the projection $\pi^{a,b}$ is the composition of these maps:
$$
  \pi^{a,b} : \MVects k\Re V_\C \overset{\varphi^{-1}}\longrightarrow \bigoplus_{p+q=k}\MVects{p,q}V \overset{\psi^{a,b}}\longrightarrow \MVects{a,b}V.
$$